# Stocktwits, how to setup the token request - babysteps

Tags: python-2.7, stocktwits

Need help understanding how the token request process works. I want to submit a post to Stocktwits via python. I understand that I need a token and need to submit criteria to 'https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/oauth/token'
How do I receive and store the token?

```
import requests, json, urllib
from oauth2 import *
client_id = 'secret'
client_secret = 'secret'
req_token_URL = 'https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/oauth/token'
```